# Fetch Bounces and Process Inbound Emails actions fail

Tags: email, bounce-processing, inbound-email

Both my Fetch Bounces and Process Inbound Emails actions have recently started failing - but only when called as scheduled jobs. When I run them manually, by clicking on 'Execute Now' they appear to run fine.

Both actions generate the same error as follows:

```
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Process Inbound Emails with result: Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore for civicrm@example.net@imap.gmail.com
Error message: 

cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 150001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I originally just noticed the issue on Fetch Bounces, and figured the issue was caused by Google deprecating support for Less Secure Apps, as Fetch Bounces was configured to collect e-mail with a standard password login, whereas Process Inbound Emails was using a different account configured for OAuth login. I tried to set up OAuth for Fetch Bounces as well, and now I have problems with both! Though I couldn't say for sure that I hadn't just not noticed that both were affected at the start.

The above errors are appearing in the logs in line with the schedule by which both actions should be run, so it seems the cron job is executing correctly.

When I execute the jobs manually through the UI it appears in the log as

```
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Success (1)
```

CiviCRM 5.48.1 and Drupal 7.89.

What's going on?